# is python's list similar in implementation to std::vector in C++

Tags: c++, python

I read that python list has random access in constant time. So in some ways, it looks similar to std::vector implementation in C++ rather than a linked list based implementation. Will someone else throw light on this?

Comment: Here's a good overview. http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/